# Execute a command with a Bash variable in it and store the result

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I don't know how to execute a command with a variable and get the result of this.
I have many `.h` and `.c` files and I need convert each from ISO-8859 to UTF-8.

So I make:

```
ls | grep "\.[ch]" | xargs myscript.sh
```

And in my script, the filename is in variable `$1`. Now I need to perform

```
iconv -f ISO-8859 -t UTF-8 $1
```

and store result of this, because `iconv` prints to stdout.

```
result=`iconv -f ISO-8859 -t UTF-8 $1`

echo $result
```

This seems to be not working, because it gives me some mismatch instead of converted `$1`.

Comment: "Some mismatch"? Please quote the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: It is not error. It is srabled content of more files then only $1, i dont understand that.

Comment: do any of the files emitted from you `ls | grep ..` have spaces in the filename? That will blow things up. Try changing to"$1" in your `result=...`, but you may need to come up with a way to handle spaces in file names. Please edit your question with approriate example values for $1 AND the exact text of scramble content. Good luck.

Comment: If your files are small enough to capture, then you need to use `echo "$result"` with the double quotes to preserve the internal spacing.  Without the double quotes, you get a single line of output with each sequence of one or more white spaces reduced to a single blank.

Comment: The canonical is *[How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437)*. Despite the unspecific title, it covers the case of ***(variable) input to the external command*** (in a (Bash) variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to do some kind of transformation on the data first, you can "capture" output with the following syntax:

```
result="$(iconv -f ISO-8859 -t UTF-8 $1)"
```

There is a gotcha here as well: if you are going to be storing large amounts of data with potential whitespace or other meddlesome characters in it, be sure to always quote the variable (`"$result"` instead of `$result`) to ensure it gets treated as a single string.

Comment: This `$cmd $1 > $1` will not just overwrite the file, it will _clobber_ it **first**. This is a good way to truncate all your source files.

Comment: Fixed again. Man, my shell is rusty.

Comment: Ok, -1 removed :) **P.S.:** these are presumably C source files, so yes, onless it was the submission for an obfuscated code contest, there is _definitely_ going to be _some_ whitespace in there :)

Comment: Thank you man, it give me some mismatch because i dont quote $result when i echoes it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do as such:

```
while read filename; 
do
    mv "$filename" "$filename.bck" && \
        iconv -f ISO-8859 -t UTF-8 "$filename.bck" > "$filename"
done < find -iname '*.[hc]'
```

This creates backups on the fly and also handles files with whitespace (not newline characters).

Comment: Double quotes handle newlines in strings (file names).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think sehe refers to `while read` when talking about newlines. IIRC, in bash you could do `while read -d $'\x00'`.

Comment: Fair enough - yes; `while read filename` won't handle newlines.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that even handles newlines:

```
find -name '*.[ch]' \
    -exec mv '{}' '{}.backup' \; \
    -exec iconv -f ISO-8859 -t UTF-8 '{}.backup' -o '{}' \;
```

Generally, *never* parse filenames if you are going to use the results. The only sane ways I know of are

1. Use shell globs, e.g. `for file in ./*.[ch] ; do echo "$file" ; done`. Only works for one directory.
2. Use [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) in combination with `-exec`
3. Use 'find' in combination with `-print0` (which prints the filenames as \0-separated strings) and use the output to build commandlines with `xargs -0` and probably a helper script. This is quite cumbersome, though.

Also, make sure that relative filenames you use are prefixed with `./`. Calling `mv -from -to` isn't safe, but `mv ./-from ./-to` is, and does what you want. E.g. when globbing, go with `./*.c` rather than `*.c`.